# Excel Variable Ranges while creating a chart

Tags: vba, variables, excel, charts

So basically I need to be able to select the last row to create a chart using this method.

```
Sub createchart2()
    lastA = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Main!$A$3:$A$10")
End Sub
```

I need the range for `A10` to be able to select the last row in the A column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub createchart2()
    Dim lastA As Long

    lastA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Main!$A$3:$A$" & lastA)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, it worked, I've been working on this all night x)