# How do I make the data update in a graph in a VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

So I figured out how to select the bottom three rows of the spreadsheet:

```
Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 6)).Select
```

However, I can't figure out how to relate my selection to the data range selected in my recorded macro:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$26:$G$28")
```

Any suggestions you have would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to make a macro that graphs the last three rows in a sheet as data is added (through another macro) over time. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985930/excel-2010-vba-activechart-setsourcedata-failed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388270/setting-a-chart-source-data-based-on-a-variable-cell-range-in-vba

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703612/excel-vba-charting-editting-the-range

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792732/excel-variable-ranges-while-creating-a-chart

Answer (score 0):

You have to **fully qualify your `Range`s**. 
This issue shows up once and again (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20605401/2707864)).

*What does this mean?* Do not use `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` or `Columns` without specifying which `Worksheet` they belong to, unless you specifically want to do that (and even in that case, explicitly using `ActiveSheet` improves readability and reduces the chances of errors, similar to using `Option Explicit`).
For instance, replace

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$26:$G$28")
```

with

```
Dim wsdata as Worksheet
Set wsdata = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=wsdata.Range("$A$26:$G$28")
```

*Note *: You can work with the `ActiveCell` only when the `Worksheet` that it is on is the `ActiveSheet` [[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221612%28v=office.11%29.aspx)].